# Why are compound assignment operators missing for kernel object?

Tags: cgal

With CGAL kernel objects, I can do `Vector + Vector`, but not `Vector += Vector`.  Same for `Point + Vector`, but not `Point += Vector`, etc. Is there any good reason for that, or are they just missing ?

The `CGAL kernel` and some algorithms require the compound operators on number types, so it looks a little inconsistent and asymmetric.

Comment: The d-dimensional kernel does provide these operators.  Only the 2D/3D kernel doesn't have them.

Comment: There is this notion that kernel objects are immutable in CGAL... For number types, CGAL didn't invent the concept. But I am a bit surprised, I thought += was precisely the exception to the immutable rule. I must misremember.

Comment: I remember this notion, although in my mind, it only covered things like not having p.set_x().  I would have a hard time finding arguments preventing +=, given that it is semantically equivalent to + and =.